# NEAR_3D function without the need for 3D Analyst, Arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy, 3d

I am looking for a Python script which would do similar as the ArcGIS 3D Analyst NEAR_3D function.

Basically I would like to programmatically in Python find nearest points of one point feature class to another point feature class and calculate their delta X, Y, Z.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing what is known as a [nearest neighbor search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search). This is quite easy to do iteratively: for each point, loop through all candidate neighbors and calculate their distance. What's challenging is how to make it efficient when you want to get the N nearest neighbors of P points and N and P are very large.

In my experience, the best balance of complexity and performance is to eschew arcpy algother and just use the [spatial.KDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) module in scipy. A k-d tree is a space partioning concept that subdivides k-dimensional space into regions that drastically reduces the number of distance formula calculations required in the nearest neighbor search. If the nearest corner of Region A is farther away from the starting point than the farthest point in Region B, then all points in Region B must be closer to the starting point than all points in Region A. Therefore, we shouldn't bother calculating a distance formula from the starting point to points in Region A.

Here's a code sample. I'm not at work so I can't test this, but it's adapted from a project where I had to find the 100 nearest neighbors to approximately 400,000 2-dimensional points. The total processing time with cKDTree was approximately 4 minutes.

```
import numpy as np
#Better to use cKDTree when not doing complicated queries
#from scipy.spatial import KDTree
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree

#Input data
MyData = [[0,0],[1,6],[2,9]]

#Convert data to numpy array, requirement for scipy classes
ArrayOfPoints = np.array(MyData)

#Create KDTree from numpy array
KDTreeOfPoints = KDTree(ArrayOfPoints)

#Iterate through points
for PointNum in range(len(MyData)):

    #Query KDTree, return distance to nearest n points and their point numbers
    #Need to have second parameter = 2 because "closest" neighbor in KDTree is itself
    Distances,Indices = KDTreeOfPoints.query(ArrayOfPoints[PointNum],2)

    #Get info about nearest neighbor.
    CurrentPoint = str(MyData[PointNum])
    NearestNeighbor = str(MyData[Indices[1])
    NeighborDist = float(Distances[1])

    print "Nearest to %s is %s, dist = %f" % (CurrentPoint,NearestNeighbor,NeighborDist)
```

Note that scipy is not part of the standard python library. It can be downloaded [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/). Use the "superpack" installer for windows as you probably don't want to build the source.

Comment: many thanks  - this is what I am looking for. I will need to add a 3rd dimension to it, but it is a really good start for me.meryloo